# How to calculate semantic similarity of words in two strings using WordNet path algorithm

Tags: algorithm, path, wordnet, sentence-similarity

I have one string of words say s1. I also have multiple strings in other set say s2, s3, s4.

I want to match the words in string s1 with each of the strings s2, s3 and so on. Based on the maximum similarity score, I want to find which strings from s2, s3 matches maximum with s1.

I want to use PATH algorithm  of wordNet. Please suggest, what should be the best approach.

Answer (score 3):

For using path similarity in WordNet, first you need to disambiguate each word with their synset in WordNet. Then you can calculate the WordNet-based similarity of two texts.

In [this paper](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/S12-1080), they called it conceptual similarity using Wu-Palmer path similarity. They basically considered synsets as concepts in the text, and Wu-Palmer path similarity as conceptual similarity measure.

If *p* and *q* are two texts, and [image: C_p] and [image: C_q] are corresponding set of synsets in these two texts conceptual similarity of two texts calculated by:

[image: ss(p, q) = \frac{\sum_{c_1 \in C_p}{\max_{c_2 \in C_q} s(c_1, c_2)}}{| C_p |}]

Which [image: s(c_1, c_2)] is the Wu-palmer similarity of two synsets.